# run an observable only after a different observable's value is true and not false

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm writing an e-commerce like application with angular 12 and rxjs.

I created a categories service that fetches with graphql categories from the server and parses them so it will be easily available in the rest of the website.

the problem that i'm having is that if a user enters a page that uses the categories service right away, then it returns an empty response because the graphql didn't return a value yet.

so I decided to create an isInitalized observable and to set it to true when it's done so the other functions to know that it's operational.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductCategoriesService {

  adminQueryProductCategories=this.gql.adminQueryProductCategories();

  isInitialized: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

  constructor(private gql: GraphqlService) {
    this.adminQueryProductCategories.valueChanges.subscribe(({data})=>{
      this.categories=data.adminQueryProductCategories;
      this.parseCategoryTree(this.categories);
      this.isInitialized.next(true);
    });
  }
```

now this is the function that fetches data from the product categories observable:

```
getCategoryTitleByLabel(label: string): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
        return this.productCategories$.pipe(map((pc: ProductCategory[]) => pc.filter(p => p.category_label === label)));
  }
```

I don't know how to implement that the observable should be executed only after the isInitialized observable is true.

any ideas?

Thank you

**update**

in general when a user browsers a category page i want to check if the category exists and if not to route him to the main page. so in the first load since the graphql request wasn't complete he's always routed to the main page.

this is the code:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.label = params['category'];
      this.pcService.getCategoryTitleByLabel(this.label).subscribe((data)=>{
        if (data.length !== 1) {
          this.router.navigate(['/']).finally(()=>{
            //TODO: popup of some sort ?
          });
        } else {
```

** update2 **

this is `productCategories$` is implemented:

```
  private productCategories = new BehaviorSubject<ProductCategory[]>([]);
  get productCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.productCategories;
  }
```

** solution **

thanks a lot for your help guys. the solution was simply to use `ReplaySubject` not `BehaviorSubject` as @BizzyBob suggested. so

instead of

```
  private productCategories = new BehaviorSubject<ProductCategory[]>([]);
  get productCategories$(): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.productCategories;
  }
```

I had:

```
productCategories$ = new ReplaySubject<ProductCategory[]>();
```

and that's it. problem resolved :)
the get category by label function stayed the same:

```
  getCategoryTitleByLabel(label: string): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
        return this.productCategories$.pipe(map((pc: ProductCategory[]) => pc.filter(p => p.category_label === label)));
  }
```

Comment: You can take a look at the [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/combination/combinelatest) operator. Every time the passed observable changes, you can check for the value and trigger a `swichMap` if true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You achieve what you are looking for by using `filter` and [`switchMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/switchmap), like this:

```js
getCategoryTitleByLabel(label: string): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return this.isInitialized$.pipe(
        filter(isInitialized => !!isInitialized),
        switchMap(() => this.productCategories$),
        map(pc => pc.filter(p => p.category_label === label))
    );
}
```

But the real problem to me seems to be with this statement:

> it returns an empty response because the graphql didn't return a value yet

`this.productCategories$` should only emit meaningful data, not "empty responses". Unless the "empty" response is meaningful, which is doesn't seem to be, they should probably be filtered out earlier in the stream.  If that were the case, you would not need to introduce the `isInitialized$` property.

Comment: thank you for your answer. the function can be called with a category that doesn't exists, or that does exist but the data wasn't initialized yet. in both cases it will return empty, how can i manage that without isinitalized? updated main post with the caller

Comment: Where is `this.productCategories$` declared?  I think we should prevent it from emitting before the data is received.  Then, downstream consumers don't need to worry about possibly race conditions, the observable will always emit meaningful values.

Comment: this makes sense. updated main post again. how can I correct that ?

Comment: Oh, I see, you use BehaviorSubject, which requires a default value.  You could try [`ReplaySubject`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/subjects/replaysubject) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```js
  getCategoryTitleByLabel(label: string): Observable<ProductCategory[]> {
    return combineLatest({
      pc: this.productCategories$,
      init: this.isInitialized
    }).pipe(
      filter(({ init }) => !!init),
      map(({ pc }) => pc.filter(p => p.category_label === label))
    );
  }
```

Comment: getCategoryTitleByLabel needs a category label as a parameter, it runs dynamically when required. i don't quite understand how can i use it in swtichmap without any parameter in the constructor

Comment: What is the source of the category label, that you want to pass to the `getCategoryTitleByLabel` function?

Comment: I updated my answer, please check it again.

Comment: I think you're talking about @BizzyBob answer, not mine. :)

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to subscribe to the BehaviorSubject observable.

You can obtain the result of the observable and perform an action:

```
this.isInitialized.subscribe((res) => {
    if (res === true)
    {
        // do something, maybe set a flag etc.
    }
});
```